# What font would compliment Source Code Pro for better readability?

Tags: website-design, web-fonts, font-recommendation

Please see this example:

[image: Screenshot of the website]

I use Source Code Pro for my website as main font. While I like the look and feel of the font and I chose it specifically for that, I have the impression, that it does not work very well for the average reader. I definitely want to keep it for my headlines and menus, but I would like to choose a different font for the blog posts content. I was experimenting with different fonts, but nothing really struck me which one could be awesome for it. I was trying Source Sans Pro, but it was too narrow compared to the headlines.

What am I looking for when I am choosing fonts for readable text and what font could possibly compliment Source Code Pro best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried Open Sans (http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans) yet? The characters are a bit more wider as Source Sans Pro and still have a modern & simple feel.

I think that Open Sans would be a suitable option in term of readability.

Comment: That is an awesome font. Much better than Ubuntu. I don't know why, but Ubuntu feels so agitated when reading it. Probably because it has a very narrow line spacing and the kerning is kinda weird. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1):

Source Sans will be the most complimentary. I initially had the same opinion but with a few adjustments to Source Sans like the font-size and letter-spacing (shown below), I think it looks great.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try Roboto

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,500italic,700,700italic,400italic,300italic,300

1. Choose the styles you want:

Thin 100, 
Thin 100 Italic,
Light 300, 
Light 300 Italic, 
Normal 400, 
Normal 400 Italic, 
Medium 500, 
Medium 500 Italic,
Bold 700 ,
Bold 700 Italic,
Ultra-Bold 900,
Ultra-Bold 900 Italic,